# Can I plug my guitar multi-effects pedal straight into the audio interface and record the processed sound via my DAW?

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal, homerecording

I want to record the sound effects from my multi-effects pedal rather than using the plug-ins that come with my DAW. I have a Tele, a Zoom G3Xn pedal, a Focusrite 2i2, and Garageband. 
Can I simply go Tele --> Zoom G3Xn --> Focusrite --> Garageband? 
Will this damage any of my equipment in any way? 
Do I need to avoid using amp-sim effects in my Zoom before I connect to the Focusrite?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Can I simply go Tele --> Zoom G3Xn --> Focusrite --> Garageband?

Yes - this is a perfectly standard way to work.

> Will this damage any of my equipment in any way?

No - not unless there's something non-obvious about your plans that you're not mentioning!

> Do I need to avoid using amp-sim effects in my Zoom before I connect to the Focusrite?

No - the Focusrite has no amp sim effects built in, so if you want an amp sim effect, turn it on on the zoom.

Answer (score 2):

The manual for the Zoom G3Xn states that its output is suitable for either a guitar amp or external powered speakers.

It should therefore be OK directly into the jack plug input of your Focusrite.   Turn the input gain right down then try - creeping the gain up gradually.   It's unclear whether the LINE or INST setting is best.  Try both (but turn the  input gain right down before switching).   One may be obviosly too hot.  Or they might both be within the range of adjustment but sound different.